# How do I access this code that my friend sent me?"

Tags: php, css

It's a .php file, and he sent it as an attachment which I received on my mac through microsoft outlook. When I open up the file, I get this text message: "This attachment was removed because it contains data that could pose a security risk." How can I fix this?

Comment: Really?  Outlook for Mac?  Microsoft probably wants to talk to you...

Comment: @Jon there is a version of the MS Office suite for Mac. The Outlook equivalent is named Entourage: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/Office2008/default.mspx

Answer (score 3):

Get your friend to rename it to a text file with a .txt extension, and re-send it again. In that way, Outlook will see a non-threatening attachment and let it through....

Comment: or paste content directly into email body as plain text (same format, almost identical effect)

Answer (score 2):

Have him send it in a password protected zip file

Answer (score 2):

Disable the safety feature in outlook.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I don't use Outlook, just have a look in the settings. I remember a checkbox of some sort.

Comment: Why disable the safety feature?!

Comment: why not? I don't see where it helps you if you are aware of the mails you get, and only open the files if they are from a source you know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible MacOS.

Here is a good website that explains how to get around it in Windows (incase anyone is wondering).

[link text](http://www.infocellar.com/msoffice/outlook-attachments.htm)